# How to limit only a specific node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am creating a social media-like platform that has a home feed. The home feed contains, posts, which can have any number of comments and likes on it. Comments can have any number of likes as well.

When the user first loads the home feed, I want to only fetch a certain number of posts at first (being 10). The query I am currently running is the following:

```
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u1:User), (u2: User {id: {id}})
WHERE u1.id = {id} OR (u1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(u2)  
OPTIONAL MATCH (u4:User)-[:LIKES]->(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u3:User)-[:COMMENTED]->(c:Comment)<-[:HAS_COMMENT]-(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u5:User)-[:LIKES]->(c)
RETURN p, u1, u3, c, u4, u5 ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

The problem here is that it will only fetch 10 results, not necessarily 10 posts. I would like a way to collect 10 posts specifically and then fetch all comments/likes/comment likes on each of those posts. Is this possible in a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may do what you intended:

```
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u1:User), (u2: User {id: {id}})
WHERE u1.id = {id} OR (u1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(u2)
WITH p, u1
ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
OPTIONAL MATCH (u4:User)-[:LIKES]->(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u3:User)-[:COMMENTED]->(c:Comment)<-[:HAS_COMMENT]-(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u5:User)-[:LIKES]->(c)
RETURN p, u1, u3, c, u4, u5;
```

It ensures that the 10 posts being picked are the most recent ones.

And it makes the reasonable assumption that every `Post` is posted by exactly 1 user (so that the `WITH` clause can be simply `WITH p, u1` instead of something like `WITH p, COLLECT(u1)`).

Comment: Thanks!! I wasn't aware you could use the limit clause before the rest of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. We just need to move the LIMIT earlier in the query to limit the posts, and only after those are limited should we start doing those OPTIONAL MATCHES.

You may also want to read up on the [WITH](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/clauses/with/) clause, for dividing up parts of a query, and the [COLLECT()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function, for collecting rows into a single list.

We can also improve the initial match, using a variable-length relationship of `0..1` so that the starting node will always be included in the match to `u1`.

We can also use [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) instead of OPTIONAL MATCHes in some cases to perform a match and collect the results in lists.

```
MATCH (post:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(poster:User)-[:FRIENDS_WITH*0..1]-(:User {id: {id}})
WITH post, poster
ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC LIMIT 10
WITH post, poster, [(u:User)-[:LIKES]->(post) | u] as usersWhoLiked
// each post, poster, and collection of liking users on a row
OPTIONAL MATCH (commenter:User)-[:COMMENTED]->(comment:Comment)<-[:HAS_COMMENT]-(post)
// now for each comment on a row, collect users who liked the comment
WITH post, poster, usersWhoLiked, comment, commenter, [(u:User)-[:LIKES]->(comment) | u] as commentLikers
RETURN post, poster, usersWhoLiked, comment, commenter, commentLikers
```

This will give you each post comment (and commenter, and the list of those who like the comment) on a row. The post, poster, and usersWhoLiked lists will show up with each associated comment.

If you want to collect the comments too, so there will only be a single post on each row, then the end of the query needs to be changed. You would need to replace the RETURN row with:

```
...
// now for each post on a row, collect the comments, commenter, and likers per comment
WITH post, poster, usersWhoLiked, collect(comment {.*, commenter, commentLikers}) as comments
RETURN post, poster, usersWhoLiked, comments
```

This is using [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-map-projection) to output, for each comment, a map of the comment's properties, as well as adding the commenter to the map, and the list of users who liked the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit the post matches first before matching the comments on the post then you should eb able to get what you want. Something like this should get you going.

```
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(u1:User), (u2: User {id: {id}})
WHERE u1.id = {id} OR (u1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(u2)
WITH p, u1 
LIMIT 10
OPTIONAL MATCH (u4:User)-[:LIKES]->(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u3:User)-[:COMMENTED]->(c:Comment)<-[:HAS_COMMENT]-(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u5:User)-[:LIKES]->(c)
RETURN p, u1, u3, c, u4, u5 
ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC
```